# Cmder not wrapping correctly while emulating bash on Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, conemu, terminal-emulator, highdpi, cmder

Not too long ago, I posted this [issue](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1392) to the Cmder GitHub page. After two weeks, it has still gone unanswered, so I was hoping to try my luck here.

Basically, I am seeing odd behavior when resizing a window in Cmder, while running bash.

Here is the issue I posted:

> To reproduce, open Cmder, and maximize the window:
>
> 1. While emulating a bash console (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows), shrink window size so that the command line (i.e. `PS1` environment
>      variable), wraps to the next line.
> 2. Run the command (can be a simple <kbd>Enter</kbd> keystroke, as long as 1. is respected).
> 3. Maximize window size, and type a command which is longer than the previous shrunken window. Line should wrap over itself.
>
> Can anyone reproduce this behavior? (Running Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.15063])
>
> I did not observe the same behavior while emulating cmd.exe.

What's more is that I don't observe this behavior while running the application "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows".

I also tried to see if the same behavior is observed on ConEmu. When I resize the screen, I get the message: "Maximum console size ... was reached Decrease font size in the real console properties", and I'm guessing this might have to do with my high DPI screen. On top of that, I get the same behavior as in Cmder.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated :D

Comment: This looks like known Microsoft Bug. You should wait when it will be fixed. https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1123#issuecomment-303153736